# Why was question "How to get the average colors used in a photo..." deleted (without giving a reason)?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, deleted-questions, dmca-notice

1. Why was this two year old SO question:
   [How to get the average colors used in a photo with RMagick in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27130090/359307)
   deleted (along with all the answers), even though question and answers had upvotes only (no downvotes)?
2. Why was *above question* deleted without giving a reason or an explanation?
3. Why can such a deletion *in general* at all happen without a reason or an explanation?
4. How can a *["Member for 5 years"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/865899/hairboat)* have an SO reputation of only  362 (*"top 77% overall"*) and still acquire the the position of a "moderator" with powers to delete quality answers which clearly are out of his scope of knowhow?

Comment: There's a comment saying *" 
Post removed due to a DMCA notice from Dreamstime"*. hairboat isn't an ordinary moderator, they're a SE employee.

Comment: To answer your 4th question, hairboat is the "Director of Community Management at Stack Overflow", so reputation is irrelevant. There was probably a good reason to remove such a question from this level.

Comment: @vaultah: Ahh, thanks for the explanation! I didn't see this comment initially (it was hidden behind the *"Show more comments"*-link). That's a good enough reason, I guess.

Comment: Couldn't the question just be redone with a different image?

Comment: @vaultah: Could this question possibly be restored if I changed the example image used in it using an non-DCMA-tainted one? (I'm not saying that I'll actually do it -- depends on time available and on how long it would take to find an appropriate replacement image.)

Comment: I even understand the downvotes for this meta question now (since I didn't search hard enough for a reason for the deletion within the comments). But couldn't the reasons for such a deletion be made more obvious?!?

Comment: It looks like 1-4 have been  answered in the comments above. I've pinged hairboat on the "restored" question - to be honest, I don't know the legals around that question.

Comment: I've deleted an obsolete comment and bolded Abby's comment so it's a little more obvious (ie: not hidden behind "show more comments") why the action was taken.

Comment: @JonClements: Thanks -- comment now stands out enough to not so easily overlook it anymore. However, IMHO deletions like that should carry their justifications right with the deletion message itself. The reason why I didn't look hard enough for the justification of the "delete" action within the comments is that I'm used to see a reason given directly whenever a question is "closed".

Comment: That's too much from stock sites.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's the story with this post. First, we received a complaint from the copyright owner via email to team@stackoverflow.com. We get similar requests fairly regularly and we process them on a case-by-case basis. For example, if a complaint seems valid and is on a -1 score post with no answers or comments, we'll delete it. If the offending material is easy to remove without breaking the context of the post, we'll do so (and leave a note in the revision history). But if we can't verify ownership or find a way to edit the post back onto the right side of copyright law, we ask the complainant to file a [DMCA takedown notice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act).

In this case, there wasn't a clear way to resolve the problem while keeping the post intact. Removing any trace of the image would have completely gutted the answer as well as the question. So, rather than delete the question prematurely, we advised the complainant to go the DMCA route. They did so and our counsel found it to be legally valid, so we were obliged to remove the post.

In my uninformed and non-legal-professional opinion, the post could be resurrected with a different image and be allowed to remain. The issue with this particular post is that we didn't see a way to change the image in the question without mangling the answer. So if the Rails or RMagick communities feel this question is a good one that should stay on the site as a resource, the best course of action in my opinion would be to re-ask a similar question using a properly licensed image and re-generate the answers based on that image. It's a pain (but intellectual property law is almost always a pain).

Now, for the general case. When we delete a post due to a DMCA takedown request, we provide notice in the following ways:

- We flag the post first, so moderators can see why it was deleted

  - (We then delete the post ourselves, clearing the flag so we aren't actually wasting a moderator's time on it)
- We leave a comment on the deleted post
- We notify the OP whose content was the violation via email (but this takes a few weeks sometimes)

It'd be nice to have a baked-in deletion reason for these, but it happens relatively infrequently (2-3 times a month by my extremely rough estimate) which at Stack Overflow's scale is minuscule. So, that's never really been proposed until now, to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, @hairboat. This clarifies a *lot* to me. It also reminds me to be more thoughtful when I use images/illustrations in my future answers (I've not had the personal resources to be very active on SO in the recent years, but still being "all time top answerer" for the *`[pdf]`* and *`[imagemagick]`* tags where I frequently used graphics to pimp my explanations, it seems these may be prone to this kind of risks more than others.)